# IIS & Tomcat running on same server. How to run both the servers on same port(443)?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, tomcat, rewrite

I have a Windows 2012 server with IIS & Tomcat running on port 443 & 8443 respectively.
Both web servers are working fine with ssl enabled on the respective ports. 
But I want to run both the webservers on the same port like below

https://example.com/home.aspx (IIS)

https://example.com/index.jsf (Tomcat)(currently it is working like https://example.com:8443/index.jsf)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Two programs can't listen on the same TCP port.

I suggest that you configure IIS on 443 and bind Tomcat to another port, and then use [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) on IIS to create [reverse proxy rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing#configuring-rules-for-the-reverse-proxy) towards Tomcat.

Comment: The first paragraph is in general incorrect for Windows. Applications can hook to the same port 443 on Windows HTTP API, but reserve different URLs, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls Your advice in the second paragraph is OK, as there doesn't seem to be enough information on whether Tomcat can bind to HTTP API like IIS.

Comment: @LexLi His first paragraph is technically correct. When using the Windows HTTP API, it's doing exactly that. It binds to those ports and the programs in turn bind to the HTTP API.